# Subtle details after running rake rails:update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I upgraded a Rails application from 2.1.0 to 2.2.2 using `rake rails:update`. This updated `config/boot.rb` and the prototype and scriptaculous files on `public/javascripts`.

Then I created two new Rails applications, one for each version of Rails.

Comparing these two applications I noticed that there are more different files (`production.rb`, `new_rails_defaults.rb`, `database.yml`, etc.)

Should I care to update manually these files in my upgraded applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `database.yml` contains your database configuration. As long as your database connection is working, don't update it.
- `new_rails_defaults.rb` contains new default settings that have changed in the new Rails version. Usually, you do not have to copy them and they even might break your current application. However, you could take a look at these settings, look them up and see if the new defaults could be useful for your application as well.
- The same holds for `production.rb`: look at the differences and only apply them if they seem useful to you, and don't break your application.